# Rails3 CMS comfortable-mexican-sofa get mismatching routing with omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I integrated [comfortable-mexican-sofa CMS](https://github.com/twg/comfortable-mexican-sofa) with my Rails 3.0.9 app with omniauth 0.2.6 in place.

Everything work fine blog side. I can log in cms-admin, working with the admin console, make a post and log off ( cms-admin has it's own authentication system, different by my app ... ), than I can browse the new post.

The problem is that the rest of my app, authenticate users with omniauth, and when I log off/on I get the following error:

```
Started GET "/auth/github" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-25 21:04:46 +0200
  Processing by CmsContentController#render_html as HTML
  Parameters: {"cms_path"=>"auth/github"}
  SQL (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "cms_sites"
  Cms::Site Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "cms_sites".* FROM "cms_sites" LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 156ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `gsub!' for nil:NilClass):
```

My Gemfile.lock is here: http://pastie.org/2270005

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Luca G. Soave

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a routing problem.

Omniauth works by detecting a 404 error page:

if it matches the route /auth/:provider, then it catches the request sends it to the provider

... but [comfortable-mexican-sofa cms](https://github.com/twg/comfortable-mexican-sofa) (like [refinery](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms) and others), has a catch all route, which is why the request never returned a 404 error, which omniauth could detect.

In comfortable-mexican-sofa case, it goes through `"cms_path"=>"auth/github"` getting

```
NoMethodError in CmsContentController#render_html
undefined method `gsub!' for nil:NilClass
```

instead of the correct omniauth path which should go like following:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-25 22:27:26 +0200
  Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
Rendered home/index.html.haml within layouts/application (29.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 44ms (Views: 42.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/auth/github" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-25 22:27:35 +0200
MONGODB gitwatch_dev['users'].find({:provider=>"github", :uid=>1573})


Started GET "/auth/github/callback?code=4334bab983hd5fec19dd" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-25 22:27:36 +0200
  Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"4334bab983hd5fec19dd", "provider"=>"github"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3001/
Completed 302 Found in 255ms
MONGODB gitwatch_dev['users'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4e23114b1d41c80f180005b2')})


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-25 22:27:39 +0200
  Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
Rendered home/index.html.haml within layouts/application (415.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 890ms (Views: 428.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

The solution in my case is like the following :

in app/controllers/errors_controller.rb

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  def error
    render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", :status => 404, :layout => false
  end
end
```

in config/routes.rb add at the bottom

`match '/auth/:provider' => 'errors#error'`

... after Omniouth last route

```
`match "/auth/:provider/callback" => "sessions#create"`
```

thanks goes to [`Federico Gonzalez`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/refinery-cms/H9Iesw072eA) and to [Oleg Khabarov](https://github.com/twg/comfortable-mexican-sofa/issues/75)

I hope this will help someone else ;-)

bye Luca G. Soave